# Nifi, CSV to Avro ValidateRecord - routing flowfile to failure because of double quote in field value

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to validate CSV to Avro using ValidateRecord processor.  The Record Reader property of ValidateRecord processor is set to CSVReader controller service. Quote Character is set as double quotes (") for this CSVReader controller service.

When I try to validate flowfiles, few of the flowfiles are redirecting to failure relationship because of double quotes present in field value.

Sample csv row from flowfile content :

"ICUA","01/22/2019","08:48:18",394846,"HAVE YOU REMOVED THE KEY?","YES---select **"Accept Response"** and continue with the remove","","","1"

I thought to use ReplaceText but this would tamper the actual value of the field.

It would be really helpful if somebody could provide the approach to deal with this situation.

Thanks!

Comment: to have a valid cvs - each double-quote inside the string must be escaped with additional double-quote.like this: `"YES---select ""Accept Response"" and continue with the remove"`.

Comment: Yes, but at this moment we don't have any control over csv generation. Basically it is auto generated by machine which is located at client site. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Fair enough but you might be left only with a scripted solution or a clever regex as daggett suggested. Otherwise you're using ValidateRecord which correctly recognizes the rows as invalid but you would like them to be valid. Perhaps you could have luck with ValidateCsv instead of ValidateRecord, as it has its own DSL for defining rules

Comment: I end up using ExecuteScript processor. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a fully functional solution.

Probably regex must be extended. So, that's just an idea:

Try to use ReplaceText with following params:

```
search:       ([^,"])"([^,"])
replacement:  $1""$2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing the direction. As mattyb suggested, apparently it seems like there are only two options to accomplish this - ReplaceText Processor and ExecuteScript process.

Answer (score 1):

To implement search and replace missing double quote, I used ExecuteScript processor using Python such as,

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processors.script import ExecuteScript
from org.python.core.util.FileUtil import wrap
from io import StringIO
import re

# Define a subclass of StreamCallback for use in session.write()
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        with wrap(inputStream) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            outer_new_value_list = []
            for csv_row in lines:
                field_value_list = csv_row.split('|')
                inner_new_value_list = []
                for field in field_value_list:
                    if field.count('"') > 2:
                        replaced_field = re.sub(r'(?!^|.$)["^]', '""', field)
                        inner_new_value_list.append(replaced_field)

                    else:
                        inner_new_value_list.append(field)
                row = '|'.join([str(elem) for elem in inner_new_value_list])
                outer_new_value_list.append(row)
            with wrap(outputStream, 'w') as filehandle:
                filehandle.writelines("%s" % line for line in outer_new_value_list)
# end class
flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
    session.transfer(flowFile, ExecuteScript.REL_SUCCESS)
# implicit return at the end
```